# How to read FAT table in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have  a run time error when I'm reading a FAT table, the error says that:

> The variable is corrupted.

This is my code

```
void Drive::readFatTable()
{
    int c = 0;
    DWORD nOBTR = 0;
    HANDLE usb = NULL;
    usb = CreateFile("\\\\.\\A:",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);
    BYTE buff[513];
    memset(buff,0,512);
    if(usb==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout<<"ERROR in reading : "<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    UINT32 fat_start = 0;//seek to table
    calc(fat_start);
    seek_to_sect(usb,fat_start,_bpb.BPB_BytsPerSec);
    LPVOID ptr = &fat_table;
    UINT32 ent = 0;
    while(c < _bpb.BPB_FATSz32)
    {
        c++;
        if(!ReadFile(usb,buff,sizeof(BPB),&nOBTR,0))
        {
            std::cout<<"ERROR in reading fat: "<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
            return;
        }
        BYTE* ptr = buff;
        for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            memcpy(&ent,ptr,32);
            fat_table.push_back(ent);
            ptr+=32;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(usb);
    std::cout<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
    //delete(&fat_start);
}
```

Comment: Probably not the issue but why do you not initialise the last element of `buff`?

Comment: Is it possible that the FAT changes asynchronously, that gets noticed and interpreted as corruption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're copying 32 bytes of data into a 4-byte variable:

```
UINT32 ent = 0;
memcpy(&ent,ptr,32);
```